# MVC Partial cshtml in C# Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to process a MVC partial file (cshtml) in an C# assembly project and return the HTML?

For example...
If I had the following MVC partial in a file within an C# assembly, is there a way to process the contents and return HTML as a string?

```
<div class="ot-item-action" data-actionid="@Model.ActionId">

    <!-- Prompt -->
    <div class="ot-item-prompt tts-content-read">@Html.Raw(@Model.Prompt)</div>

    <!-- Formats -->
    <div class="ot-item-numeric-container">
        @Html.Raw(new NumericInput(1, Model.Format).WriteHtml())
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You can try using Razor Engine https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/index.html, but I am not sure that it supports all the features

Comment: Thanks.  But I want to do this using Microsoft .NET MVC Razor.